# MySQL Error 1064 in basic PHP Proccess and not in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have syntax created by user post to my PHP file, and marge all in one syntax, this example finish my Query of PHP:

```
INSERT INTO `Table 1` (....) VALUE (....) ; INSERT INTO `Table 2` (....) VALUE (....); INSERT INTO `Table 2` (....) VALUE (....);
```

but why in php have error code 1064, and in phpmyadmin (application php) is not have any error?

**Edit :**

My Full Syntax retrun from my php to MySQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO `Transaksi` (`BKC ID`,`Dari`,`API KEY CABANG`,`Pola Bayar`,`Produk`,`Tujuan`,`Nama Pengirim`,`Alamat Pengirim`,`Telphone Pengirim`,`Nama Penerima`,`Alamat Penerima`,`Telphone Penerima`) VALUE ('PLM170423000002','Palembang','e6eeefa86700890ccab7bca533574c576d7798b1','Tunai','Hari Ini Terima','Jambi','Abdul Aziz Al Basyir','Jln. Sukabangun 2','0816388833','Steven','Jln. Maksimal','0899121212121') ; INSERT INTO `Transaksi Barang` (`BKC ID`,`Isi Barang`,`Variabel`,`Satuan`,`&#162; Koli`,`Harga`) VALUE ('PLM170423000002','Sepeda','12','Koli','12','96000'); INSERT INTO `Transaksi Barang` (`BKC ID`,`Isi Barang`,`Variabel`,`Satuan`,`&#162; Koli`,`Ket Tambahan`,`Harga`) VALUE ('PLM170423000002','Motor','12','Kilo','5','Keterangan Motor','72000');
```

Comment: `Error 1064` is a syntax error. Your code doesn't seem to have a syntax error, but on the other hand, your code is incomplete. Can you post the full query? If not, can you reduce your query to a short example that still triggers the error, and post that then?

Comment: are you sure that your php mysql   allow multiple sql statements in a  query???

Comment: @Pharaoh, this example return from my file php (i show you in my Questions

Comment: Please post the _PHP_ code that builds and executes this SQL statement. It was noted that you have multiple SQL statements, and that is not supported by most MySQL APIs in PHP.

Comment: @scaisEdge, i dont know about that but if server can't support that, phpmyadmin have too.., but why phpmyadmin success but in my php syntax not?

Comment: In phpadmin  each statements is separated and excuted  by semicolon. in php you should check if is allowed  this beahvior

Comment: for @MichaelBerkowski, i will ask to my owner of server because i only using cpanel like server hosting.., thank for help..

Comment: @scaisEdge,  i will ask to my owner of server because i only using cpanel like server hosting.., thank for help..

Comment: What PHP driver and function are you using to execute this query?

Comment: @chris85, i use a my class, and in class i use function ``mysqli_query("{query}","{connection}");``

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir That order is inverted but per the manual `mysqli_query` only supports 1 query. `Performs a query against the database.` vs. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php `Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.` The reason not to use `multi-query` is if you are open to SQL injections an attacker could exploit any table/DB the DB user has access to.

Comment: @chris85, ohh if i want to make mysqli_multi_query() in my class, Is this function dangerous for my php?

Comment: I don't know where the data you are putting into your queries comes from. Possibly.